# Max amount of elements to append

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying should be easy, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out (ore google the problem)

I have elements that I find, after finding them I want to append them to a container. But I don't want to many items so I want to be able to limit the amount of items to be appended.

For example:

```
<div class="appending">

</div>

<div class="toAppend">

    <div class="box project">
      <h3>Project Box</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="box project">
      <h3>Project Box</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="box social">
      <h3>Social Box</h3>
     </div>

    <div class="box video">
      <h3>Video Box</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="box project">
      <h3>Project Box</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="box social">
      <h3>Social Box</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here are 3 items in div.toAppend that I would like to append to the div.appending

```
var appenditems = $(".toAppend").find(".project");
appenditems.appendTo(".appending");
```

This is easy, but my problem is that I want to limit the amount of div.project that are appended , for example, only append the first 2 that I find. I'm unsure of any way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...for example, only append the first 2 that I find.

```
appenditems.slice(0,2).appendTo(".appending");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

```
var appenditems = $(".toAppend").find(".project:lt(2)");
appenditems.appendTo(".appending");
```

Comment: I would not have thought of that, interesting. But of browser compatibility I'm going to go with the jquery .slice() :) But I'm going to write that one down to remember.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery's Slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
var LIMIT = 2;
var appenditems = $(".toAppend").find(".project");
appenditems.slice(0, LIMIT).appendTo(".appending");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JDXTF/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector which select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

```
$(".toAppend").find(".project:lt(2)").appendTo(".appending");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.toAppend .project:lt(2)').appendTo('.appending');
```